# Automatically remove tag

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I want to automatically remove 'tag1', from a heading if I either assign a scheduled or due date or 'tag2' to it.

Just to clarify, there is:

```
* Some heading :tag1:tag3:
```

If I add 'tag2', it becomes:

```
* Some heading :tag2:tag3:
```

If I add a scheduled date, it becomes:

```
* Some heading :tag3:
  SCHEDULED: <2022-09-21 Wed>
```

Can this be done? How?

Comment: It depends on how you add tags: if you do it manually, then you will have to delete it manually. If you use `org-set-tags-command` (bound to `C-c C-q` in the Org mode keymap), then you could advise `org-set-tags` to check the tags: if both `tags1` and `tags2` are present, then delete `tags1` before the "real" `org-set-tags` is called. Similarly, you can advise `org-schedule`, `org-deadline` and/or `org-time-stamp` with an after advice: if they've inserted scheduling information, then call `org-get-tags`, check for `tags1` , delete if if present and  call `org-set-tags` with the new tag set.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. I use `org-set-tags-command` to manage tags.

I guess, I will need to write a function to remove 'tag1' if present and then add that function to the advice.

(advice-add :before 'org-set-tags-command #'remove-tag1)

(advice-add :after 'org-schedule #'remove-tag1)

But no matter how hard I try, I am not able to get the 'remove-tag1' function.

Could you please provide some pointers?

Comment: I provided a (partial) answer on how to remove a tag under certain conditions. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: how to remove a tag

```el
  (defun ndk/remove-tag ()
      (org-set-tags (delete "tag1" (org-get-tags))))
```

This needs to be applied while *at* the appropriate headline.

Comment: Sorry - I got rid of the extraneous `let`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `org-after-tags-change-hook` hook to remove TAG1 conditionally.

```lisp
(defun remove-tag-if (&optional remove-tag1)
  (let ((tags (org-get-tags nil 'local)))
    (when (or (and remove-tag1 (member "tag1" tags))
              (and (member "tag1" tags) (member "tag2" tags)))
      (org-set-tags (delete "tag1" tags)))))

(add-hook 'org-after-tags-change-hook 'remove-tag-if)
```

And to also remove it after `org-schedule`, use:

```lisp
(advice-add 'org-schedule :after (lambda (_) (remove-tag-if 'tag1)))
```

Comment: Instead of `(member (and "tag1" "tag2") tags))`, I think you mean `(and (member "tag1" tags) (member "tag2" tags))`  - right?